# Grouping Cypher query results by direct relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given the following graph (where all relationships have the `FOLLOWS` type), how can we get the results such that they are grouped according to previous and next node(s) of a given node?

```
 H->G->E->D
     ->F
```

- Where H follows G
- Where G follows both E & F.
- E follows D

So given some property of G, expecting results in the form:
`[{H}, {G}, {E, F}, {D}]`

Tried:

```
MATCH (prev:Person)<-[:FOLLOWS *0..]-(p:Person)<-[:FOLLOWS *0..]-(next:Person) WHERE p.name ='G' RETURN collect(prev), p, collect(next) as result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, there looks to be two types of solution.

To show what I mean I'll use this slightly more complicated graph that includes a merging of `FOLLOWS` downstream from `H`:

```
                                ┌───┐
                          ┌────▶│ J │
                          │     └───┘
┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐
│ H │──▶│ G │──▶│ E │──▶│ D │──▶│ I │
└───┘   └───┘   └───┘   └───┘   └───┘
          │               ▲
          │               │
          │     ┌───┐   ┌───┐   ┌───┐
          └────▶│ F │──▶│ L │──▶│ K │
                └───┘   └───┘   └───┘
```

To group every path from `Person` with `name = 'H'` by length, showing the same `Person` more than once (because there is more than one path from, for example, `H` to `D`), use this:

```
MATCH p = (:Person {name: 'H'})-[:FOLLOWS*0..]->(e:Person)
WITH length(p) AS l, collect(e.name) AS people
RETURN collect(people) AS result
```

Result:

```
[["H"], ["G"], ["E", "F"], ["D", "L"], ["I", "J", "D", "K"], ["I", "J"]]
```

If instead you want each person to appear once, you can use the `shortestPath` function like so:

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((:Person {name: 'H'})-[:FOLLOWS*0..]->(e:Person))
WITH length(p) AS len, collect(e.name) AS people
RETURN collect(people) AS result
```

Result:

```
[["H"], ["G"], ["E", "F"], ["D", "L"], ["K", "I", "J"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

your description and your example are not exactly the same : you say "previous and next node(s) of a given node" and your example has two sets : next and after next

given the following nodes

```
create (:Person {name:"H"})-[:FOLLOWS]->(:Person {name:"G"})-[:FOLLOWS]->(:Person {name:"E"})-[:FOLLOWS]->(:Person {name:"D"});
match (g:Person {name:"G"}) merge (g)-[:FOLLOWS]->(:Person {name:"F"})
```

[image: screenprint of nodes created]

here is a possible query

```
match (prev:Person)-[:FOLLOWS]->(p:Person {name:"G"})-[:FOLLOWS]->(next:Person)
optional match (next)-[:FOLLOWS]->(next2:Person)
return collect(distinct prev.name),p.name,collect(distinct next.name),collect(distinct next2.name)
```

[image: query result]

here is the other query

[image: other query and result]

Comment: Thank you for this, it was helpful in my learning process. Gave me a different result on different graph. Apologies for any confusion in my question. Learning.